# showing Json data

Tags: javascript, html, json

i've tried to show a result like this from a json file using a for loop [showing country's flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAk5x.png)

i've tried this code but he show just one flag **i think the problem in the for loop** but i can't solve it 
if you can help me !

```css
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",run, false) ;

function run(){ 

    document.getElementById("bouton").addEventListener("click",action , false) ; 
    
    function action(){ 
    
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest() ; //variable qui contient les éléments en lien avec les requêtes
    var url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/regionalbloc/EU"; 
    request.open("GET",url ,true) ; // traitement de l'objet sur lequel on applique une méthode 
    request.send() ; //envoyer la requête
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){ //onready..... va être appeler a chaque modification de l'etat de la requête (0;1;2;3;4)
         
    if ((request.readyState==4)&&(request.status == 200)){ // 4=requete terminer+réponse prête ; 200= requête c'est bien dérouler sans pb
        objJson = JSON.parse(request.responseText)[23];//JSON.parse on convertit la reponse de la requete en json qui est identifier par objJson;on veut du texte on parse le Json
        chaine="<ul>";
        for (prop in objJson){

            if (prop=="flag"){
                chaine+="<li>"+prop+": <img width='150' src='"+objJson[prop]+"'/></li>"
            }  
                      }
            chaine +="</ul>";
            document.getElementById("zone").innerHTML=chaine;
             }
          }
      }
  }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Drapeaux des continents</title> 
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
<script src="taac.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
 <h1>Drapeaux des continents</h1> 
   <select name="parfum">
    <option value="EU">EU </option>
    <option value="AU">EFTA </option>
    <option value="AU">CARICOM </option>
    <option value="AU">PA </option>
    <option value="AU">AU </option>
    <option value="AU">USAN </option>
    <option value="AU">EEU </option>
    <option value="AU">AL </option>
    <option value="AU">ASEAN </option>
    <option value="AU">CAIS </option>
    <option value="AU">CEFTA </option>
    <option value="AU">NAFTA </option>
    <option value="ESP">SAARC </option >
   </select >


 <button id="bouton" >Recherche</button>
 <div id="zone"/div-->
</body> 
</html>
```

there is another way to do this ? because i can't find where is the problem exactly in my code
 Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Added changed logic:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",run, false) ;

function run(){ 

    document.getElementById("bouton").addEventListener("click",action , false) ; 

    function action(){ 
    var e = document.getElementById("country");
var country = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest() ; //variable qui contient les éléments en lien avec les requêtes
    var url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/regionalbloc/"+country; 
    request.open("GET",url ,true) ; // traitement de l'objet sur lequel on applique une méthode 
    request.send() ; //envoyer la requête
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){ //onready..... va être appeler a chaque modification de l'etat de la requête (0;1;2;3;4)

    if ((request.readyState==4)&&(request.status == 200)){ // 4=requete terminer+réponse prête ; 200= requête c'est bien dérouler sans pb
        objJson = JSON.parse(request.responseText);//JSON.parse on convertit la reponse de la requete en json qui est identifier par objJson;on veut du texte on parse le Json
        //console.log(request.responseText);
        chaine="<ul>";
        for (index in objJson){
            prop = objJson[index];
            //alert(prop['flag']);return false;
            if (prop['flag']){
                chaine+="<li>"+prop['name']+": <img width='150' src='"+prop['flag']+"'/></li>"
            }  
                      }
            chaine +="</ul>";
            document.getElementById("zone").innerHTML=chaine;
             }
             else{
             document.getElementById("zone").innerHTML= "";
             }
          }
      }
  }
```

and changed from

```
<button id="bouton" >Recherche</button>
    <div id="zone"/div-->
```

to

```
<button id="bouton" >Recherche</button>
    <div id="zone"> </div>
```

Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/m7Lcpbw6/

Comment: no idea why downvote. its working example. corrected code with list of country flag. If possible give explanation,

Comment: Idk why you got downvoted, but my guess would be the lack of explanation.

Comment: didn't got what you trying to explain. But as per question solved answer and added extra changes.

Comment: the problem with this is showing always the same flags

Comment: Check latest changes

Comment: Only works on the first time the button is clicked and if you refresh and try again the same flags are displayed regardless of the selection.

Comment: Question was not showing list of flag to correct logic. I corrected his issue. Other changes are extra thing he need to consider

Comment: not workin you can try , choose EEU it's not the correct results always same results

Comment: you other value to AU whenever it change it will pick it from it.